# how to write Realm nested objects?

Tags: swift, realm

i have this realm structure:

```
class DateLog: Object {
    dynamic var date = NSDate()
    let workouts = List<WorkoutLog>()
    let activities = List<ActivityLog>()
}

class WorkoutLog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var value = 0
    dynamic var notes = ""
}

class ActivityLog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var value = 0
    dynamic var notes = ""
}
```

**how can i add to realm DateLog > WorkoutLog data?**
(date for DateLog; name, value, notes for WorkoutLog)?

the workflow i'm looking for:

1. add new record to date log (just a date)
2. add workout log record for that date (with all details)
3. add activity log record for that same date

Answer (score 7):

Just create and add your DateLog object to Realm inside a write block:

```
let realm = try! Realm()

try realm.write {
    var dateLog = DateLog()
    dateLog.date = NSDate()

    var workoutLog = WorkoutLog()
    workoutLog.name = "My Workout"
    workoutLog.value = 1
    workoutLog.notes = "my note"

    dateLog.workouts.append(workoutLog)

    realm.add(dateLog)
}
```